# How to query child lookup objects correctly in Conga Composer?

Tags: query, lookup, conga, conga-composer

I have a query added to a solution. The query fetches data from child a child record, but when I try to get name of fields in Template Builder, the fields that I select are provided in a format within a table :
[image]

I try to map {{XXX}} to get the value of it outside of the table and it returns a blank value (Empty), but within the table it's full.

Is there something else I should be doing ?